# Can multiple tables each `belongTo` fileupload and each fileupload have no relationship in model?

Tags: cakephp, model, foreign-keys, belongs-to, has-one

I am playing with using a table of file uploads (fields: `id, name, size, type`) and using a series of other tables (notes, filings) each with a foreign key pointing to one record in the file uploads table (field: `upload_id`).  The model for each of the series of tables (e.g., notes, filings) would include belongTo relationship pointing to the file uploads table.

That means the file uploads table will have no foreign key (multiple tables point to it) so a foreign id field wouldn't work unless I had a field for every other table (e.g., `note_id`, `filing_id`, etc.).  The model would not mention any relationship.

Should I do it another way?  I can't think of a more efficient one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends basically from the business logic.

If your files are distributed between other tables (notes fillings etc.) then the

Upload hasMany Note
Upload hasMany Filling

but this is in case when you have only one file per record.

If you have case when a note or filling has more than one file then you need to go to HABTM relaion or:

```
Table notes:
id, name, desc ...

Table uploads:
id, name, size, type

Table notes_uploads:
id, note_id, upload_id

Table fillings_uploads:
id, filling_id, upload_id
```

So you will define a many to many relation to each entity which has files in it.

I think the second way is the more flexible one, but really depends from the requirements.